# Confused on where it says that the inverse is unique on the Property of Existence of a multiplicative inverse

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation, real-numbers

> For every number $ a \ne 0 $, there is a number  $ a ^{-1} $ such that
> $$ a . a^{-1} = a^{-1} . a = 1. $$

This line is from Calculus by Michael Spivak.

I wanted to prove $ (ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1} $ using the basic properties of numbers and [i did this same solution as xbh(1st ans) in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112274/proving-ab-1-a-1b-1-if-a-b-ne-0).

This solution uses the idea that each inverse is unique, hence proving both term is equal.

**Since I am just relying on the basic properties and definitions, how do I know that the inverse is unique. Are the words that I quoted from Spivak enough to say every number has a unique inverse or there is something I missed?**

Comment: No, you missed nothing. The fact that the inverse is unique has to be proved (but it's easy to prove it).

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you! I will look for the proof

Comment: @AnotherUser I found the proof

Comment: @AnotherUser Your comment should be posted as an answer since it answers the question.